# Does DWR support method calls with GET?

Tags: java, ajax, dwr, http-get

Does DWR support method calls with GET?
So I can use http caching to cache the result of the call...
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it does support that since engine.js in DWR 2.x has an option "`httpMethod`" with which you can specify GET; from [the docs](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/browser/engine/index.html):

> Selects use of GET or POST. Called
>   'verb' in 1.x, likely to be removed in
>   version 3.0

The options can be set globally or at a call level. I haven't used that option myself, though. (And it is marked as deprecated.)

(About caching, I'm not sure. All I quickly found was [this page](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/browser/engine/static.html) which talks about caching engine.js and the scripts generated by DWR.)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set it to GET method
 Firstly, we have to set an  in web.xml for dwr config to allow GET

```
<Init-param>
       <Param-name> allowGetForSafariButMakeForgeryEasier </ param-name>
       <Param-value> true </ param-value>
</ Init-param>
```

Secondly, before calling any method using dwr, we must set    `dwr.engine.setHttpMethod("GET");`

Found the resolution from the below link, modified a bit to suit for dwr 2.0/3.0 http://blog.intropedro.com/es/tema/dwr